# Redirect sub-domain to a folder using .htaccess

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, symfony

I know this question has been asked many times on SO, but My problem is different and I'm not able to find the solution.

I've a Domain name(**`https://mydomainname.com`**) registered from GoDaddy and the site is hosted on AWS EC2. This site has a blog which is hosted on Azure with sub domain (**`https://blog.domainname.com`**).

The thing is, main site is on Amazon EC2 which is developed in Symfony and the Blog is on Azure developed in Wordpress. Now is there any way we can point sub-domain to the sub folder using .htaccess. 
(**`https://domainname.com/blog`**)

I think without transferring the files on single host it's not possible,  then what is the work around to get it done in Symfony framework.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create redirect rule at your Azure hosting.

In the root of the `blog.domainname.com` website, create a file named `Web.config` with contents as this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Redirect blog domain to main domain" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url=".*" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^blog\.domainname\.com$" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="http://domainname.com/blog/{R:0}" redirectType="Permanent" />
                </rule>              
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```